# how to store count of values that are repeated in an array into map in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, stl

I was trying to store count of words repeated in an array of string...

```
int countWords(string list[], int n)
{
    map <string, int> mp;

    for(auto val = list.begin(); val!=list.end(); val++){
        mp[*val]++;
    }
    int res = 0;
    for(auto val= mp.begin(); val!=mp.end(); val++){
        if(val->second == 2) res++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

but I was getting error like:

```
prog.cpp: In member function int Solution::countWords(std::__cxx11::string*, int):
prog.cpp:14:32: error: request for member begin in list, which is of pointer type std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*} (maybe you meant to use -> ?)
            for(auto val = list.begin(); val!=list.end(); val++){
                                ^
prog.cpp:14:51: error: request for member end in list, which is of pointer type std::__cxx11::stri.................
```

someone please look into this once.

Comment: how are you calling the function? `list` is just a pointer to `std::string` . Even if you used `->` the `begin` and `end` is most likely not what you want (because that would be iterators into a single `std::string`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `list` is an array, which does not have a `begin` method (or any other method).

This could be fixed by changing the function to take a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of an array.

If you want to keep it as an array, the `for` loop should be changed to this, assuming `n` is the length of the array:

```
for(auto val = list; val != list + n; val++)
```

In C and C++, an array is somewhat equivalent to a pointer to the first element of the array; thus `list` gives the start pointer, and `list + n` gives a pointer to after the end of the array.

Comment: `list` is not an array. It is a pointer. Probably it does point to the first element of an array, nevertheless the difference is crucial, because for an array one could use `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Answer (score 1):

`list` is a pointer, it does not have `begin` or `end` members, nor is it a valid input to `std::begin` or `std::end`.

If you have `n` strings in an array, pointed to by `list`, then you can iterate them by constructing a [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span).

```
int countWords(std::string list[], int n)
{
    std::map<std::string, int> mp;

    for(auto & val : std::span(list, n)){
        mp[val]++;
    }
    int res = 0;
    for(auto & [key, value] : mp){
        if(value == 2) res++;
    }
    return res;
}
```